Copy specific axis location from an armature to another
I made a walking cycle animation.
However I noticed that in some frames my eyes' target is not aligned with the eyes like the rest of the frames.
(When I look with N at the transform location, both have a location of 0,0,0).
Is there an easy way to set the z axis of this armature to be the same as the eyes' armature? Or any other method to keep the direction the eyes are looking at alligned?



Have you tried using a CopyRotation constraint?
